# Comparing 2 values ​with deviations in Excel

Tags: excel, function

I want to compare 2 motherboard lists in Excel to see if they match.

Unfortunately, here are discrepancies between the names. Is there a function that can check if the string from the 2nd list occurs in the 1st list and then return the boolean value?

I already tried the MATCH-function and EXACT-function without succes.

[image: Motherboard Lists]

Comment: Can you show your match formula? You can use a IF to return the boolean, inside the if, you could use a match/xmatch, or vlookup/xlookup...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MATCH` and `SUBSTITUTE`.
Enter the following Array-formula (ctrl-shift-ENTER) assuming Mainboard List 1 is in B3:B9:

```
=MATCH(FALSE,SUBSTITUTE($B$3:$B$9,C3,"")=$B$3:$B$9,0)
```

It returns #NV if there is no match - otherwise the index.
The formula is case sensitive.
Furthermore it wont find "GIGABYTE X48-DS4" in "GIGABYTE Technology Co. Ltd. X48-DS4 (Socket 775)" but it finds "X48-DS4" in "GIGABYTE Technology Co. Ltd. X48-DS4 (Socket 775)".

Use `=MATCH(FALSE,SUBSTITUTE(UPPER($B$3:$B$9),UPPER(C3),"")=UPPER($B$3:$B$9),0)`
for a case-insensitive version. If you want to find "GIGABYTE X48-DS4" in "GIGABYTE Technology Co. Ltd. X48-DS4 (Socket 775)" search first for "GIGABYTE" and then for "X48-DS4". You have a match if both formulas return the same index.